# Makefile: run based on test of variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile with a rule to build several targets and create a single package from it.

```
TARGETS=t1 t2 t3 t4

pack_it:
    -for t in $(TARGETS); do \
        $(MAKE) -C $$t install DESTDIR='temp' ); \
    done
    tar czvf package.tar.gz -C tmp *
```

Now I'd like to be able to pass, from command line, which targets I want to pack, like this:

```
make pack_it t1 t4
```

How must I test the arguments to know if I should run `make install` on a target?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just override `TARGETS` from the command line:

```
$ make pack_it TARGETS="t1 t4"
```

No need to change anything in the makefile.